# How to make http post request signed with OAUTH in java with JSON object to be passed as body?

Tags: java, json, http-post, rest

I have a requirement to call a rest api post method which accepts two parameters username(optional query param) , inputBody(required param of JSON object but not json string) which is to be passed to "BODY" not query parameter.

These are the steps that I followed to make the call:

1. created an oauth consumer object that is used to sign the request and httpclient object to execute the
   request

   ```
     consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer("abc", "def");
     requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(300 * 1000).build();
     httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
   ```
2. Creating the post request with json

   ```
    json_string = " {"id":"erv" , "age": 18 , "country" : "IND"} "  // This is the json string 
    updatereq = new HttpPost("BASEURL/object");
    updatereq.setHeader("Id","xyz");
    StringEntity input = new StringEntity(json_string);
    input.setContentType("application/json");
    updatereq.setEntity(input);
   ```
3. Signing the request with OAUTH credentials

   `
   try {consumer.sign(updatereq);  // SIGNING THE REQUEST}

   ```
        catch(OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        catch(OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     `
   ```
4. Finally executing the request to get the response code

   ````
     updateresponse = httpClient.execute(updatereq);
     int updatehttpResponseCode = updateresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
     System.out.println("post Response Code :: " + updatehttpResponseCode);
     if (updatehttpResponseCode == 200) 
       { 
        System.out.println("POST request worked);
       } 
     else 
        {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
        }
      ```
   ````

OUTPUT:

post Response Code :: 400
POST request not worked

I am receving the "http bad request" response for the request I am making.
How can I solve this issue?
should I need to change the request format by specifying any additional headers/parameters to make this work?
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please try adding below lines? `updatereq.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); updatereq.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");`

Comment: @Govind Thanks a lot man : ) it did work now and the response of post was 200. I still do not understand how the json string is getting converted into a json object and sent as body in the request but my purpose has been served.